# How to get files from created directory in ionic? using get() method and show it on screen

Tags: ionic3, angular5, cordova9

I want to display the files in created directory. The files may be any format like audio, video, image etc. This is How I able to create a directory and remove directory.
Home.ts

```
 createDirectory(){

    this.file.createDir(this.file.externalRootDirectory, "DirectoryFile", false )
    .then((directoryEntry) =>{

      alert("directory created"+ directoryEntry.fullPath);
    }
  ).catch((error)=>{
    alert(JSON.stringify(error));
      })

  }

  removeDirectory(){
    this.file.removeDir(this.file.externalRootDirectory, "DirectoryFile")
    .then((resultData) =>{
      if(resultData.success){
        alert("directory removed" + resultData);
      }
    })
      .catch((err) =>{
      alert(JSON.stringify(err));
    })


enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [listDir](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/file/)

```
listDir(path, dirName)
  List files and directory from a given path.
```

```js
this.file.listDir('some/path/directory', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried like this but am getting [obj obj] on screen

```
    listAllFiles(){
    this.file.listDir(this.file.externalRootDirectory, "DirectoryFile")
    .then((entry) => {
      this.showFile=entry;
    })
    .catch((err) =>{
      alert(JSON.stringify(err));
    })
  }
```

Comment: Can you please send the code, how to display all the directory files